# How do I successfully set working directory?

Tags: directory, working-directory

I've tried everything to load a csv file from my computer but can't get it to load, because an error says "no such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection."

I've tried to change the working directory, and looked at other troubleshooting threads and tried everything, but it keeps saying "cannot change working directory." And when I go to session>set working directory, I can't select anything from my computer, the only thing that comes up is "R projects."

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.